# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. custom hooks with nested functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have created a custom React Hook that has a function that will dispatch an action to redux store.

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toggle } from "../state/reducers/togglePassSlice";

const useToggle = () => {
  const { showpass } = useSelector((state) => state.toggle);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const togglePassVisibility = () => {
    // console.log(showpass);
    dispatch(toggle(showpass));
  };

  return { togglePassVisibility };
};

export default useToggle;
```

on my component when i try to call it, i get an error: **Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

```
import EntryCard from "../../components/EntryCard/EntryCard";
import InputGroup from "../../components/InputGroup/InputGroup";
import Input from "../../components/Input/Input";
import Button from "../../components/Button";
import { EntryPage, PageHader } from "./style";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import useToggle from "../../hooks/useToggle";

const SignInPage = () => {
  const { togglePassVisibility } = useToggle();

  const toggle = togglePassVisibility();

  return (
    <EntryPage>
      <PageHader to="/">AWESOME LOGO</PageHader>
      <EntryCard>
        <h2>login</h2>
        <form>
          <InputGroup>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Input type="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" />
          </InputGroup>
          <InputGroup>
            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <Input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="password" />
          </InputGroup>
          <Button type="submit" full="true">
            Sign in
          </Button>
        </form>
        <span>
          Dont have an account?
          <Link to="/signup"> Sign up</Link>
        </span>
      </EntryCard>
    </EntryPage>
  );
};

export default SignInPage;
```

how do i solve this error and pls what is a better way for this approach with custom hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at these lines in particular:

```
const SignInPage = () => {
  const { togglePassVisibility } = useToggle();

  const toggle = togglePassVisibility(); // this calls dispatch every render!

  return ( /* ... render ... */ );
}
```

Every time your component is rendered, you immediately call `togglePassVisibility()` which will cause a new render. This is an infinite loop.

If you instead want to be able to call `togglePassVisibility` as if it were called `toggle`, you can do one of the following:

- don't invoke it when assigning it to `toggle`:

```
const toggle = togglePassVisibility; // <-- no parentheses
```

- assign it using deconstruction:

```
const { togglePassVisibility: toggle } = useToggle();
```

- in your hook, export an array instead:

```
// in hooks file
const useToggle = () => {
  /* ... */
  return [ togglePassVisibility ];
};

// in component
const [ toggle ] = useToggle();
```

**Note:** Don't forget to bind toggle to a button.